# getting the error on Vector2Pool.obtain in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I am trying to run sample program for Accelerometer using andengine
[enter link description here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/UnTagged/andengineexamples/org/anddev/andengine/examples/PhysicsExample.java.htm)

But i am not able to run program. I added andenginephysicsbox2dextension.jar also.

Having support this method only Vector2Pool.obtain();[remove arguments to match obtain()]

In ex :   final Vector2 gravity = Vector2Pool.obtain(pAccelerometerData
                        .getY(), pAccelerometerData.getX());

And Log error :Could not find method org.anddev.andengine.entity.shape.IShape.getVelocityX, referenced from method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your AndEngine version is old. I guess you should clone it again.